# antlr tree parser grammar

Tags: antlr

I have a grammar file that can generate ast. How can I write `tree grammar` that can traverse the `tree generated`?I have some examples from the Internet, but while  I can understand them I don't know how to write them from scratch myself.For example:

ExprTree.g

```
stat: expr NEWLINE -> expr   
     | ID '=' expr NEWLINE -> ^('=' ID expr)   
     | NEWLINE ->   
;   

expr: multExpr (('+' ^|'-' ^) multExpr)* ;   
multExpr: atom ('*' ^ atom)* ;   
atom: INT   
     | ID   
     | '(' ! expr ')' !   
;   

ID  :   ('a'..'z'|'A'..'Z')+ ;   
INT :   '0'..'9'+ ;   
NEWLINE: (('/r'? '/n')|';')+ ;   
WS  :   (' '|'/t')+ { $channel = HIDDEN; } ;
```

ExprEval.g

```
stat: expr 
| ^('=' ID expr)     ;   

expr   
: ^('+' a=expr b=expr) 
| ^('-' a=expr b=expr) 
| ^('*' a=expr b=expr) 
| ID        
| INT
```

ExprTree.g is grammar that generate ast and ExprEval.g can traverse the tree.For rule expr in ExprEval.g,why not this:

```
expr: multExpr (('+' ^|'-' ^) multExpr)*
```

Comment: http://vimeo.com/groups/29150/videos/sort:oldest You may watch through the steps, as the video clips are quite good.

Comment: Can you post the parser grammar and your attempt of the tree grammar?

Comment: @BartKiers,my grammar is very large ,it isn't appropriate to post it.I think I just want some general suggetion or instruction about how to write grammar that can traverse a tree.

Comment: @BartKiers,thank you so much.But I am not able to access blogspot.Is there anywhere else that has similar content with your blog?

Comment: @BartKiers,I've downloaded it.thank you again!